# Enable Windows Defender Firewall rule only on specific network

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender

A network I often connect to logs me out from iTunes. I've set up a rule in Windows Defender Firewall to block iTunes from connecting to the internet, does anyone know of a way to only have that rule enabled for a specific wireless network? I'm on Windows 10. Thanks.

Comment: What's the network profile of your wireless network? How about applying the rule only for that profile?

Comment: Are you talking about Public vs Private? I've done that and set it as public, but I want to be able to use it on other public networks. I might just have to enable it and disable it manually for now.